# Существуют ли SQL системы, не являющиеся сервером и хранящие данные в файле?

Tags: php, sql

Существуют ли portable SQL системы, которые хранят базу данных в файле и не являются приложением для которого открыт порт. Мне предпочтительней, чтобы такая система работала на php, ну или являлось расширением.

Comment: Это значит, что вам нужна "in-proc file-based database" или "embedded database. Посмотрите SQLite и SQL Server Compact Edition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вот это вот по дефолту используется в андроиде.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite

Comment: и не только это же linux ну и можно добавить http://php.net/manual/ru/book.sqlite.php для php